# Shiny disable selectinput but the users can see the available options, but I cannot select them

Tags: shiny-server, disabled-input

Good morning, 
I have a selectinput with several options. I need that this input is disabled, but the user can see the available options, but I cannot select them.

Thank you

I mean, I have a selectinput in shiny with a list of questions from 1 to 100. How do I make the person see the questions, but cannot select any, like disabling them. It would be disable in Selectinput, but the person can see the available options.

selectInput(inputId = "question", label = "questions", choices = c("question1", "question2", "question3", "question4", "question100" ) ),

Thank you

Comment: Please provide a full reproducible example in for me to help.

Comment: ok I already put the selectinput example

Answer (score 1):

Using the package `shinyjs()`, you can use the `disable` function although this doesn't allow you to see the dropdown choices. So... only half way answers your question, not sure if it is possible to see the choices.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

#####/UI/####

header <- dashboardHeader()
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()
body <- dashboardBody(
  useShinyjs(),
  selectInput(inputId = "question", label = "questions", 
              choices = c("question1", "question2", "question3", "question4", "question100" )
              )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

#####/SERVER/####
server <- function(session, input, output) { 

  shinyjs::disable("question")

  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, there may be some other ways to get the same affect (i.e. not having the dropdown start a reactive unless another condition is met, etc.)